# Developing Scheduled tasks in Java and running on Linux server

Tags: java, linux, spring, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

I wanted to develop 'tasks' in Java which can be run periodically as per the schedule defined.

How do I run this on my Linux server. If it is a jar file - is it enough that I create a jar file and run it using shell script? and schedule to run the script (CRON)

I was planning to make use of Spring Framework. Do I really need one? Since I can schedule to call my java program using CRON

How do I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the app using Spring Boot and run it as a daemon:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html

And then use quartz to schedule tasks

Answer (score 0):

You can use CRON job and as well as scheduler like (Quartz etc) to run your java task. I think CRON job is a convenient way to run your jar file. You can simply schedule your jar in the CRON job.

Answer (score 0):

Check out quartz its an awesome **scheduling library** that you can include in any `java` application.

Once  the scheduler is started it runs in selected intervals defined in  a `cron` expression say
 `( ***** )`